# fstrim is not functional after migrate to vmfs6 without reboot

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi, thin-provisioning

I have Vmware esxi 6.5. Now I migrated some thin provisionied VMs to VMFS6. When I call `fstrim /`I can except that vmdk file will smaller, but without error in console - vmdk is not smaller. I must reboot every VM after vMotion to VMSF6. After it is ok and fstrim do smaller vmdk.

Is it some rescan here for it to avoid reboot every VM?

Tried:  `echo "1" > /sys/class/block/sda/device/rescan` or  `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`

In dmesg:

```
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda]  Sense Key : Illegal Request [current]
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda]  Add. Sense: Invalid command operation code
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] CDB: Unmap/Read sub-channel: 42 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00
end_request: critical target error, dev sda, sector 30214032
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Cache data unavailable
sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

Thank you.